# Link/mouse over background image not clickable on IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hyperlink, background, click

This is my site

www.landshoppe.com

My links and searchbox in the over laying divs of the  header portion with background image is not clickable in IE 8. Is this an inherent IE Z-index problem ? (Though I have given a Z-index 5 for the searchbox div). Or is this a position issue ? (I have assigned position relative to the div).

The page validates in W3C validator. So no html errors.

Where is the glitch ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a specific stylesheet for IE. Reference it using conditional comments like this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

And add in the CSS - for the **clickable area** - these attributes:

- A background color (any color, it does not matter). E.G.: **background-color:** *#000000*;
- **ms-filter:** *"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"*;
- **filter:** *alpha(opacity=0)*;

This solved it for me!

Comment: Thanks for the info, Consta Gorgan. I did add the background-color and the filters into the style sheet. Still no luck. In fact the div disappeared ! This is what I added  #searchbox{position:relative:text-align:center;padding:5px;width:60%;margin:0px auto;margin-top:20px;z-index:5;background-color:#000000;
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);filter: alpha(opacity=0);}

Comment: I've played a little bit with your code, but I can't figure out where the problem resides.

Also you should read this similar thread: [Overlay not clickable in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868108/overlay-not-clickable-in-ie8) maybe it helps

Comment: Hi Consta, are you also finding same issue in IE with my code  ?

Comment: I seem to find filter:prog id in css the issue

Comment: Glad you found the solution! Good luck further!

Answer (score 0):

@Consta Gorgan  I found a solution by putting all the events inside the div into another within this div and making its position:absolute. Now it works ! Though I have some issue in mobile responsive design. Guess I will tackle that as next level :)